# Adding Markers on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to update a marker in real time on a Google Map. I need a marker for the starting location and then as the location changes (the user moves) a polyline will be drawn and a marker will show the current location. So, for each user there will be two markers; one showing the start location and one that keeps updating and showing the current location.

I can get the lines drawn and the start marker to work, but with this code each time the location changes, a new marker is placed instead of the old one being updated. I'm trying to use setPosition(); but it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

```
   function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39, -86);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }       
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 

    var loc = {};
    var mark = {};
    var markers = {};

    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({                                      
                    url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
                    //data: "",                       
                    dataType: 'json',                //data format      
                    success: function(data){          //on recieve of reply                          


                        var user_id = data[0];
                        var lati = data[1];              //get id
                        var longi = data[2];           //get name

                        var myLatlngt = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);

                        if (typeof loc[user_id] === 'undefined') {
                            loc[user_id] = [];
                            }

                        //if (typeof markers[user_id] === 'undefined') {
                            //markers[user_id] = [];
                            //}

                        if (typeof mark[user_id] === 'undefined') {
                            mark[user_id] = myLatlngt;
                            }

                        loc[user_id].push(myLatlngt);
                        //markers[user_id].push(myLatlngt);
                        var marker1;
                        var x;
                        for (x in loc) {
                            var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                map: map,
                                path: loc[x],
                                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                strokeWeight: 2
                                });
                            polyline.setMap(map);

                            ///location variables
                            var start_loc = loc[user_id];
                            var start_marker = start_loc[0]; //start location of given user
                            var current_loc = start_loc[start_loc.length -1]; //last known location of given user

                            //set the start marker
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: start_marker,
                                title: user_id
                            });
                            marker.setMap(map); 

                            //update the current location marker
                            if (marker1 != null) {
                                marker1.setPosition(current_loc);
                            }
                            else {
                                marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: current_loc,
                                    map: map
                                });
                            }                   
                        }
                            //console.log('location :::', x);
                            console.log('Marker: ', mark);
                    } 
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your **marker1** variable (`var marker1;`) outside the function to make it global (scope). Right after `var markers = {};` should do it. Let me know if this does not work, and I will look in to it deeper.

Comment: It worked! But now I have another issue. If I'm tracking two users the current location marker will jump from user to user instead of having a marker for each. Any idea as to why?

Comment: What if I want to create them on the fly? Like how my polyline can be created for multiple users instead of creating a bunch of global variables.

Comment: Well, each marker is a variable, but you can have an array full of markers. You can add and remove markers from the array and use the key (maybe) to identify the user each belongs to. Something like… `$myMarkers[userId].setPosition(current_loc);`